# Hive drop table from MYSQL metstarore TBLS table

Tags: mysql, hive, metastore

In Hive, How to drop a table from from MYSQL metstarore TBLS table

Comment: have you tried `drop table ...` from hive?

Answer (score 1):

Use the drop table statement, do not drop tables manually from the mysql db because this will probably end in a non-consistent state in the db

```
drop table TABLENAME;
```